# Remove array element if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove an element from the array `ids` if the element doesn't exist.

```
<div id="nl-form-0" > 
  <input type="text" id='dynamic_translation_0_0' value="15" />
  <input type="text" id='dynamic_translation_0_1' value="15" />
  <input type="text" id='dynamic_translation_0_2' value="15" />
  <input type="text" id='dynamic_translation_1_2' value="15" />
</div> 

ids = [
  "transliterateTextarea",
  "dynamic_translation_0_0",
  "dynamic_translation_0_1",
  "dynamic_translation_0_2",
  "dynamic_translation_1_0",
  "dynamic_translation_1_1",
  "dynamic_translation_1_2"];

check_remove_ids_array(ids);
console.log(ids);
console.log($("#dynamic_translation_1_1").length);

function check_remove_ids_array(array_in) {
  array_length = array_in.length;

  for (n = 0; n <= array_length; n++) { 
    if ($("#" + array_in[n]).length == '0') {
        removeValue(ids,array_in[n]);
    }          
  }     
}

function removeValue(arr, value) {
  var array = arr;

  for (var i = array.length-1; i--;) {
    if (array[i] === value) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

In the above code `dynamic_translation_1_1` does not exist. I want to remove that or any other element from the array `ids` if the element doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

### Why does/did it not work?

Basically you had a return and assigning problem. Since there are no reference parameters in JavaScript you have to assign the returned array back to the initial ids. Same goes for your removeValue() function.

### Suggestion

Use the array.filter() prototype instead. It solves your problem more elegantly.

### Example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                ids = ["transliterateTextarea", "dynamic_translation_0_0", "dynamic_translation_0_1", "dynamic_translation_0_2", "dynamic_translation_1_0", "dynamic_translation_1_1", "dynamic_translation_1_2"];
                ids = check_remove_ids_array(ids); //We have to assign it back, else we always get the initial ids array!
                console.log(ids);
                console.log($("#dynamic_translation_1_1").length);
            });

            function check_remove_ids_array(array_in){
                array_length = array_in.length; //Is not required in this example anymore.

                //We use the filter function instead.
                return array_in.filter(function(item){return $("#" + item).length > 0})
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = 'text' id = 'dynamic_translation_0_0' value = '15' />
        <input type = 'text' id = 'dynamic_translation_0_1' value = '15' />
        <input type = 'text' id = 'dynamic_translation_0_2' value = '15' />
        <input type = 'text' id = 'dynamic_translation_1_2' value = '15' />
    </body>
</html>
```